# Implications of disabling the AMD Phenom's TLB patch?

Tags: cpu, amd-phenom

I'm currently running a *AMD Phenom X4 9600* processor (yeah, it's aging a bit, but other recent problems mean it's not getting upgraded in the immediate future), which happens to be one of the chips that suffer from the TLB errata.

I recall that the first time I played with disabling the TLB patch (probably over a year ago, while playing a game that had a *severe* performance problem such that it was almost unplayable unless the patch was disabled) I had at least one BSOD, but I can't remeber them being *particularly* frequent. However, because it decreased instability, I stopped disabling the patch once I was done with the game.

Now, after some recent hardware changes I was experiancing much worse performance than expected from the new hardware under some circumstances, and the TLB jumped to mind - after testing I found that disabling the patch would improve the performance to expected levels.

I'm now wondering if it's worthwhile *always* having the patch disabled to avoid any potential slowdowns cropping up in the future, or if it is too dangerous. Everything I read states that the bug, when not patched, can causes a system lock-up in "rare circumstances".

### So, with the TLB patch disabled:

- How frequently should system lock-ups be expected?
- Do we know *what* the circumstances that trigger the lock-ups are?
  (Don't worry too much about being highly technical, but essentially I wonder if the chip more vunerable under heavy load, or heavy memory usage, etc?)
- Are there any secondary problems I should be aware of?
  (Don't include things that are charateristic to all lock-ups, please)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [AMD Phenom TLB Patch Benchmarked and Explained](http://www.legitreviews.com/article/618/1/), quoted from AMD :

> It’s unfortunate that the TLB erratum
>   that affects the AMD Phenom 9500 and
>   9600 processors has garnered as much
>   attention as it has. Unfortunate not
>   just for AMD, but for customers
>   because I believe it has been blown
>   out of proportion. [..] It is
>   extremely unlikely desktop users are
>   going to find themselves in a scenario
>   that could trigger this erratum. [..]
>   We’ve communicated a BIOS modification
>   to motherboard vendors that will
>   ensure system stability, and we’re
>   implementing a silicon fix in future
>   CPUs. But what really stands out to me
>   is that we put a switch in the AMD
>   OverDrive utility that enables PC
>   users to disable the BIOS workaround.
>   That should send a message of our
>   confidence that desktop users should
>   not lose sleep about this particular
>   erratum.

As it says : Don't lose sleep about it.

Comment: Thanks, that's good enough for me. I'll run with the patch disabled for a while, if I hit any real problems I'll update here.

Comment: Update: I've been using the patch disabled since my last comment and as a result receive maybe one or two BSOD crashes per week, most often while gaming, but otherwise the machine is stable.